# the if statement is redundant java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a class for an application which has methods checking if the current time is within a specified range.

```
public boolean visitorEntry()
{
    currentTime = LocalTime.now();
    start = LocalTime.of(8, 30);
    finish = LocalTime.of(22,0);   

    if (currentTime.isAfter(start) && currentTime.isBefore(finish))
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I am using NetBeans and am being told that the if statement is redundant. I assume my condition is logically incorrect and always evaluates to true but I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its correct, but unrequired.... you can just do this: `return currentTime.isAfter(start) && currentTime.isBefore(finish)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What it means is you can write :

```
return currentTime.isAfter(start) && currentTime.isBefore(finish);
```

On NetBeans, if you hit Alt-Enter while the cursor is on `if` and select "The if statement is redundant" it will do this simplification itself.

Answer (score 7):

I guess it means you can write your function like this:

```
public boolean visitorEntry()
{
    currentTime = LocalTime.now();
    start = LocalTime.of(8, 30);
    finish = LocalTime.of(22,0);   

    return currentTime.isAfter(start) && currentTime.isBefore(finish);
}
```